# hide.php files with variables htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, hide

i have a problem on my htaccess file , i'm trying to hide all .php extensions on my website,
i tried many htaccess codes but most of it gives me errors , 404 Not Found , most of my files contain variables like ?id and ?category , index/?cat=Action , i want htaccess to hide php extension and forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php , help me pls :)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# turn off index.php for home page
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [L,R=301,NC]


# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Wrong way of going about it. You have to detect your "no .php extension" URLs, and re-write them TO a .php file. e.g. "detect /foo/bar, rewrite to /foo/bar.php"

Comment: i want to change the ?id = /id

Comment: yes, but you need to have the friendly urls ON THE CLIENT. e.g. the user's browsers should show `/id`. then your rewrite would `RewriteRule ^(\d+) whatever.php?id=$1` if you're sending "ugly" urls to the client to start with, then all of this is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write php to the end of urls not the other way around.  You can write variables like this: `href="foo?bar=1"`. This code has worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: i want to change the ?id = /id

Comment: Did you write this requirement clearly in your question? If not clarify all these cases by editing your question and I will try to answer them.